# How should I conceal this wire?

Tags: electrical, trim, trim-carpentry

In order to put in a 220v line an electrician ran this line from my circuit breaker into the adjacent room. Putting aside that there may have been other ways to do this, how would you conceal it? I guess I could use some 1x2s to make a little box around it and then paint that. Any better ideas? This is in an entryway.

[image]

Comment: That electrician disrespected your home; as did the person who spray foamed that corner. Don't mess around with your box idea unless you have to. Try simply painting the line to match the wall first. If you want to get fancy then crown molding could help. Something simple like a 1x4 from wall to ceiling could also work.

Comment: Wow - unless you told you electrician you want to change to the "industrial look" that's really unimpressive ... and what's going on in that corner?

Comment: What a choice, between "cheap" and "ugly."

Comment: Why is there a breaker in the entryway? Why is the door a terrible inaccessible trip hazard? WTF is that hump in the corner? Why so many conduit clips passive aggressively placed? How can those coat hooks by the door both be in studs?  so many questions...

Answer (score 5):

There are other ways to do it - they cost more, of course. Without knowing what discussion you had with the contractor, that's a murky subject. Stock electrician approach to conceal the cable is to rip open the ceiling for access and you have a drywall and paint person come in to fix that after them, as electricians don't *do* drywall or paint. I'd expect something like this if lowest cost was the most important factor; it does look exactly like it was done with that in mind.

Molding would be the most likely approach to look decent - you'll need both crown and corner trim to get the whole thing covered, and will want to carry it around the whole room for a consistent look, as opposed to looking like you put molding up to hide a cable just where a cable was run. That will deal with the ugly spray foam, too.

Should be obvious, but **don't nail through the cable.** Yeah, it happens - just don't let it happen to you.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with the crown molding (which can.be fiddly to install), a soffit box is certainly a legitimate way to enclose the cable. Though you might want to try painting it to match the wall first and see if that reduces it's visibility enough to live with. (Here in the US, the cable would probably have been run through basement or crawl space under the floor, then up inside the wall.)

Comment: The soffit box is good because there's already one in that room that can be matched.